# Can someone explain this causality argument about the speed of light from Special Relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, faster-than-light, causality

I was watching this [Yale lecture by R. Shankar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URC7QU1XCRw).

From [8:29](https://youtu.be/URC7QU1XCRw?t=8m29s) to [15:05](http://httphttps://youtu.be/URC7QU1XCRw?t=14m35s), he gives an argument for why theory of relativity "demands" that it should be impossible for events to influence other events faster than the speed of light and once you accept that there are no logical contradictions in the theory.

For some reason I am not able to follow this argument. Can someone explain **clearly** what the argument is.

Comment: There are some classic problems that ask you to show that retrocausality is possible if we allow FTL (faster-than-light) signaling. That is to say, I can send a message to my past self telling him what horse to bet on, after the fact. Obviously, things can travel at exactly the speed of light—namely, light. This should convince you, more computationally than philosophically, that light is the universal speed limit—just because retrocausality doesn't make physical sense.

Comment: The essence of the argument is that relativity is internally consistent, and *if you accept a priori that reality conforms to the theory*, then faster-than-light speed is impossible. The problem with many mathematicians is that they don't admit the possibility that anyone may reject the axioms of the theory (or at least may insist that they be proved or supported rather than blindly assumed), so they express themselves in ways that strike ordinary people as logically fallacious - essentially, what he means to say is true, but what he's saying isn't what he means.

Comment: @MarcusAurelius, I would argue that "retrocausality" in the manner you describe is absurd - not because of the limited speed of light, but because what you're describing is not movement in time, it is the resetting of all things in *space*. That is, to re-run the horse race with a tip from the future, you would have to find a way of putting the horse spatially *back in* behind the starting gate - not just finding a way to ensure that the horse leaves the gate in a time after you had gained the tip. It's got nothing to do with the speed of light, and everything to do with your confused concepts

Comment: I was just thinking of an example on the fly, unfortunately it didn’t work in this case, sorry!

Comment: @MarcusAurelius, don't worry, I find those sorts of examples are common currency in physics. The fact that "retrocausality" has a name shows in how bad shape physical philosophy is. When things exceed the speed of sound, occurrences do not become "retrocausal", they are simply mediated (in a causal fashion) by the thing that goes faster than sound. If anything goes faster than light, the same would be true.

Comment: The speed of sound is a non example though as frame-passing with a Lorentz boost of the speed of sound doesn’t do anything fundamentally drastic to space-time. It becomes apparent when you look at a minkowski diagram—the axes get flipped with this type of boost, and you can use this to derive unphysical phenomena.

Comment: @MarcusAurelius - While I've little doubt you guys understand this better than I, might I mention that light usually travels *slower* than the speed of light - since it rarely travels in a perfect vacuum. It is **gravity** that travels at the speed of light (and probably a number of other *things* too). -- Also 'light communication' is simplex (single direction) but gravity (and the like) is duplex ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_(telecommunications) ). Also, in reference to your 'horse race example', you don't *know* that the communication wouldn't change the outcome you'd expect.

Comment: The horse race was a poor example but let me try to think of a better one. Consider events A and B such that A has caused B. With a FTL Lorentz boost we pass to a frame where B precedes A, which is absurd.

Comment: @MarcusAurelius - Not relativistic (or *is* it?) but: Event A = "You want to go to the store to buy some eggs". Frame B = "Everyone else wants to go to the store to buy some eggs". --- Now you get up enough energy to go to the store and guess what, no eggs; but you were certain that it was an original idea (obviously I'd need to change my example). -- Also use "@" if you want a specific person to be altered to your reply. Back in a few hours.

Comment: @Rob since the point of this whole discussion is to avoid other problems with introducing examples of how FTL allows retrocausality, I prefer situations with less spatial variables like stores and eggs. Information transmission between two individuals is good: Alice tells Bob a unique key code, and Bob uses it to decrypt a file. Then FTL Lorentz boost has, in another frame, decryption before unique key.

Comment: @Steve Marcus' example is fine. The *point* is that it is absurd. And yet if you accept the theory of special relativity and also allow for unrestricted faster-than-light travel, one can send signals to the past. Or even *go back* to the past, when the horse is still in the gate. Since that is absurd, SR+FTL is an incompatible theory.

Comment: @Chris, I simply don't see FTL travel as implying signals going "to the past". The past as we know it is not merely a reference to a place in time, it is a reference also to a configuration of things in space *at that time*. Correspondingly, slower-than-light space travel (or zero travel) does not imply that we are "sending things to the future" (in the discontinuous sense, of not having to employ an ongoing physical process of getting it there). To go back to the past we would have to commandeer the necessary processes to *get there* (i.e. physically force babies back into wombs, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

A speed $v$ exists for which $\Delta x =v\Delta t$. Then $\Delta t'=\gamma(\Delta t - c^{-2}u\Delta x)=\gamma\Delta t(1 - c^{-2}uv)$. To preserve the order of events in a Lorentz transformation, we need $\Delta t'$ to have the same sign as $\Delta t$, so $1 - c^{-2}uv>0$ or $uv<c^2$. The special case $v=c$ achievable by a light beam provides the constraint $u<c$ for any relative velocity between reference frames related by Lorentz transformations.